# Interfacing LEDs at communication lines for a RS232 to RS485/RS422

Tags: led, rs485, rs422

I want to use LEDs at the output of R232 to RS485 & RS422 converter to indicate the Rx and TX activities. This converter will be inside an enclosure and I want the RX TX activities to be indicated by LEDs. At page 13 and page 14 of [this manual](http://ftp.icpdas.com/pub/cd/8000cd/napdos/7000/manual/7520.pdf) specs for this particular model **7520A** of the converter is given.

Here is the terminal for RS485 RS422 and power pins:

[image]

And below shows the block diagram and the configuration I want to use:

[image]

[image]

I want to add an LED for indicating D1+ D1- RS485 communication.
And I want to add two LEDs for RS422 between TX+ and TX- and between RX+ and RX-.

How can this be achieved? Would a resistor in series corrupt the data? I dont have experience with such interfacing is it even possible?

Edit: The specs of small LEDs I want to use is [here](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1579/0900766b81579777.pdf).

Edit2:

[image]

Comment: What do you want the LEDs to do? Flash when there's data? I think you probably want a microcontroller receiving the data and handling flashing the LED, just putting one across the data lines would be pretty meaningless.

Comment: Yes I want them to flash with the data. I thought if I buffer or use a series resistor would be adequate. Why a microcontroller?

Comment: 1mA LEDs ought to be adequate with >1000mcd @ 20mA with suitable Rs on RS232 which uses +5/-5V. Choose Blue Green or White for 3V

Answer (score 2):

I would not suggest just adding the LED across the + and - wires of the diff-pairs like you propose even with a resistor in series with the LED. The LED data sheet that  you linked shows that the operating current for LED is 20mA. That current level is enough to compromise the signalling levels on the differential interfaces.

A much better method is to realize that you can indicate activity by just monitoring the + or - wire individually. I would then consider just connecting the wire to an inexpensive logic level small signal N-FET gate. Ground the source lead of the N-FET and the drain terminal connects to the LED+resistor that gets tied to a positive supply voltage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to draw it here what you said https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jAEp.png I have 2N7000 at the moment and I need to use 24V supply. What do you think about this way? (I only used D1+ RX+ and TX+ as you say)

Comment: I would not recommend connecting anything directly to the differential lines, as this is likely to create an impedance mismatch. Instead, I would connect buffers to the transceiver chips and use those to drive the LEDs.